# Efficiently getting from a QPaintDevice to a QSGTexture in QQuickItem

Tags: qt, scenegraph, qquickitem

My custom QQuickItem currently does the following

1. Create a QSGNode that subclasses QSGSimpleTextureNode
2. In the nodes preprocess function, create a QOpenGLFramebufferObject to draw to
3. Draw on the QOpenGLFramebufferObject using a QPainter
4. Display the contents of the QOpenGLFramebufferObject as the node contents

The process I have for converting the FBO to a QSGTexture that I can set on the QSGSimpleTextureNode is the following.

```
QImage img = m_fbo->toImage();

QSGTexture* tex = m_window->createTextureFromImage(img, QQuickWindow::TextureCanUseAtlas);

setTexture(tex);
```

This seems very inefficient, and the app starts to get real framey even with relatively reasonable sized FBOs.

My questions are the following.

1. Is there a simpler way of getting an FBO into a QSGTexture?
2. Is there a better QPaintDevice compatible item that I should be using rather than a QOpenGLFramebufferObject?
3. Is there a better subclass I should be extending than QSGSimpleTextureNode to do what I am wanting to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) For non multisample framebuffer objects a texture with the specified texture target is created. You can get the texture id for the texture attached to framebuffer object, using [QOpenGLFramebufferObject::takeTexture()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglframebufferobject.html#takeTexture). And then
create a new `QSGTexture` object from an existing GL texture id:

```
QSize textureSize = m_fbo.size();
GLuint textureId = m_fbo.takeTexture();
QSGTexture* texture = window()->createTextureFromId(textureId, textureSize);
```

2, 3) The `QQuickPaintedItem` class provides a way to use the `QPainter` API in the QML Scene Graph.

The `QQuickFramebufferObject` class is a convenience class for integrating rendering using a framebuffer object (FBO) with Qt Quick.

Comment: In regards to QQuickPaintedItem, can you still override updatePaintNode to be able to create a node subtree?

Comment: how can I pass this `QSGTexture` created finally in step 1 into the `updatePaintNode` ? Or in other words, how can I display this `QSGTexture`  on my QQuickItem ?